# What audio format should I use to compile cocos2d on android?

Tags: android, audio, cocos2d-android

When i run my cocos2d game on iphone the only sound file that work is .caf

But in android i was try with .mp3 .ogg .aac .wav, and no one of these is working.

i'm testing on android 4.4 and 5.0

With what sound file does cocos2d-x 3.3 work on android?
Or what change can I make in my code?

```
#include <SimpleAudioEngine.h>
bool HelloWorld::init()
{

auto audio = CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance();

audio->preloadBackgroundMusic("FunTime.mp3");
audio->setBackgroundMusicVolume(5.0f);

audio->playBackgroundMusic("FunTime.mp3", true);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using AudioEngine instead of SimpleAudioEngine. It works perfectly fine with mp3.

Example:

```
#include <AudioEngine.h>

bool HelloWorld::init()   {
cocos2d::experimental::AudioEngine::play2d("FunTime.mp3" ,true,5.0f);
}
```

You can also preload the audio if you want.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Volume value (range from 0.0 to 1.0). ?

Comment: 1 is full volume, 0 is mute.

Comment: then `5.0f`  is more than limit so `play2d("FunTime.mp3" ,true,1.0f);` is better for understanding